# Merge associated items from an activerecord relation result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

How do I combine for example all the `Tag.has_many :images, through: :taggings` from a bunch of `Tag`s?

Something around this unless theres something simpler:

```
images = ???
Tag.where("name in (?)", tag_params).each do |tag|
  images = images.merge(tag.images)
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
images = Image.joins(:tags).where(['tags.id in (?)', tag_params])
```

?

Comment: Whoops, for some reason i tried to simple it down but i shouldnt have. Added the through: part

Comment: Yeah this way is much better, just change it to `images = Image.joins(:tags).where("name in (?)", tag_params)` and ill set this as answer